# Rails nested layout exception

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the typical application layout in rails. All my views require

```
<div class="container">
```

with the exception of my root landing page, which has a jumbotron banner that stretches the entire width of the browser window.

At this point I've patched together nested layouts to enforce the "container" div on every other view, but I'd rather apply to the master layout and simply exclude the  from my root (home.html.erb) view.

Any ideas?

Comment: why not just use the application layout for everything and define an alt layout for the home page?

Comment: Seems logical, but I would still like my home page to inherit the additional properties from the application layout. I was able to remove the "container" class by applying some js on my home page, but it seems like a hack to me.

Comment: Just duplicate the features (simplest solution)

Comment: the JS is a kinda hackish.  You could also just do something in your application layout to test which controller/action you are and not include the container/div tags.